# modelbuilder stuck values during iterating

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I am creating a model that finds all the tracks(points) a wolf pack leaves who cross into a park using select by location, easy. I than want to find all the tracks(points) those same wolfs made on those same trips before and after leaving the park. The problem I am having is after the first feature class is successfully processed it stops iterating through one side of the join.

Exe

```
cuting (Iterate Feature Classes): IterateFeatureClasses "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb" Puppy* POINT NOT_RECURSIVE
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:32:11 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:32:14 2018 (Elapsed Time: 2.56 seconds)
Executing (Make Feature Layer): MakeFeatureLayer "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb\Puppy_08_13_16_17" Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layer # "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb" "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;Groupie Groupie VISIBLE NONE;sm_group sm_group VISIBLE NONE;dt dt VISIBLE NONE;lat lat VISIBLE NONE;long long VISIBLE NONE;LG_num LG_num VISIBLE NONE;SM_num SM_num VISIBLE NONE"
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:32:14 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:32:14 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.23 seconds)
Executing (Select Layer By Location): SelectLayerByLocation Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layer WITHIN Park # NEW_SELECTION NOT_INVERT
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:32:14 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:33:38 2018 (Elapsed Time: 1 minutes 23 seconds)
Executing (Summary Statistics): Statistics Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layer "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb\Puppy_08_13_16_17_stat" "Groupie FIRST" Groupie
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:33:38 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:34:25 2018 (Elapsed Time: 46.73 seconds)
Executing (Add Join): AddJoin Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layer Groupie "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb\Puppy_08_13_16_17_stat" Groupie KEEP_COMMON
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:34:25 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:34:25 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.17 seconds)
Executing (Save To Layer File): SaveToLayerFile Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layer "C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr" # CURRENT
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:34:25 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:34:25 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.11 seconds)
Executing (Feature Class to Feature Class): FeatureClassToFeatureClass "C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr" "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb" zPuppy_08_13_16_17_cross_park # "Puppy_08_13_16_17_Groupie "Groupie" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.Groupie,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_sm_group "sm_group" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.sm_group,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_dt "dt" true true false 8000 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.dt,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_lat "lat" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.lat,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_long "long" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.long,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_LG_num "LG_num" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.LG_num,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_SM_num "SM_num" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.SM_num,-1,-1;F_Name__stat_Groupie "Groupie" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17_stat.Groupie,-1,-1;F_Name__stat_FREQUENCY "F_Name__stat_FREQUENCY" true true false 0 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17_stat.FREQUENCY,-1,-1;F_Name__stat_FIRST_Groupie "FIRST_Groupie" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_13_16_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17_stat.FIRST_Groupie,-1,-1" #
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:34:26 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:36:16 2018 (Elapsed Time: 1 minutes 50 seconds)
Executing (Iterate Feature Classes): IterateFeatureClasses "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb" Puppy* POINT NOT_RECURSIVE
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:36:16 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:36:16 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.20 seconds)
Executing (Make Feature Layer): MakeFeatureLayer "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb\Puppy_08_10_12_17" Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layer # "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb" "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;Groupie Groupie VISIBLE NONE;sm_group sm_group VISIBLE NONE;dt dt VISIBLE NONE;lat lat VISIBLE NONE;long long VISIBLE NONE;LG_num LG_num VISIBLE NONE;SM_num SM_num VISIBLE NONE"
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:36:16 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:36:17 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.25 seconds)
Executing (Select Layer By Location): SelectLayerByLocation Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layer WITHIN Park # NEW_SELECTION NOT_INVERT
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:36:17 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:36:57 2018 (Elapsed Time: 40.65 seconds)
Executing (Summary Statistics): Statistics Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layer "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb\Puppy_08_10_12_17_stat" "Groupie FIRST" Groupie
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:36:57 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:37:20 2018 (Elapsed Time: 22.93 seconds)
Executing (Add Join): AddJoin Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layer Groupie "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb\Puppy_08_10_12_17_stat" Groupie KEEP_COMMON
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:37:21 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:37:21 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.16 seconds)
Executing (Save To Layer File): SaveToLayerFile Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layer "C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr" # CURRENT
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:37:21 2018
Succeeded at Thu Jan 25 15:37:21 2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.09 seconds)
Executing (Feature Class to Feature Class): FeatureClassToFeatureClass "C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr" "C:\Modelbuilder\Wolf.gdb" zPuppy_08_10_12_17_cross_park # "Puppy_08_13_16_17_Groupie "Groupie" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.Groupie,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_sm_group "sm_group" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.sm_group,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_dt "dt" true true false 8000 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.dt,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_lat "lat" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.lat,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_long "long" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.long,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_LG_num "LG_num" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.LG_num,-1,-1;Puppy_08_13_16_17_SM_num "SM_num" true true false 8 Double 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_13_16_17.SM_num,-1,-1;F_Name__stat_Groupie "Groupie" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_10_12_17_stat.Groupie,-1,-1;F_Name__stat_FREQUENCY "F_Name__stat_FREQUENCY" true true false 0 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_10_12_17_stat.FREQUENCY,-1,-1;F_Name__stat_FIRST_Groupie "FIRST_Groupie" true true false 4 Long 0 0 ,First,#,C:\Modelbuilder\Puppy_08_10_12_17_Layerfile.lyr,Puppy_08_10_12_17_stat.FIRST_Groupie,-1,-1" #
Start Time: Thu Jan 25 15:37:21 2018
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a Remove Join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the last step in your model a [Remove Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/remove-join.htm) as @BERA suggested.  If that doesn't work on it's own, try putting everything after Make Feature Layer into a submodel with the feature layer as a parameter of that submodel.  That should force ModelBuilder to reevaluate the feature layer with every iteration.

Comment: I have tried both suggestions with no luck. It appears to be a problem with the join. The join is permanently on the initial feature class and not on the iterated feature class. I tried %Name%.joinfield but it didn't like that.

Comment: Try putting everything inside the iterator in a submodel.  That might trick it into dealing with the join properly.